# Why was question about origin and meaning of "rackers" closed as basic?

Tags: discussion, appropriate-questions

Why was the [question about origin and meaning of "rackers"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63737/origin-and-meaning-of-rackers) closed as basic?

Not only I was surprised in this choice, but other ELU' member ("asking for an explanation of a line of Shakespeare is just as on-topic as asking to 'explicate'a newspaper editorial. (Admittedly, there are other reasons to be uneasy about this question."), too.

Comment: I voted to close the original question because *"rackers" (people who rack/torture)* was Shakespeare's poetic/metaphoric usage *(torturers of orthography/spelling)* over four centuries ago, and there have probably been few if any related usages ever since. I don't particularly mind ELU addressing metaphoric usages in current newspaper articles (that might be repeated, and which native speakers would normally understand). But one-off Shakespearean usages that haven't become well-known to later generations seem to me to be well and truly off-topic (basically, they're Lit. Crit.)

Answer (score 6):

The question was closed as "general reference" because, at least as written, you were asking us to do the job of a dictionary.

The good news is, it would be easy to improve the question so that it could be reopened:

- Look up the word in a dictionary or two or three, and add the information you find there into the question.
- Describe why the dictionary definition doesn't help you to make sense of the quotation.
- Tell us exactly what the quotation is from. (Hint: it's not actually from any historical person named Holofernes.)

Comment: As the "other ELU member", I entirely agree with this.  But one unfortunate feature of the system is that two close votes for one reason, and three for another, will close the question *even though the two voters disagree with the three on both topics*.  I think, though,  Carlo has got his answer (particularly since the question has been re-opened)